# Spring SecurityContext in Async Controller Response

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-restcontroller, security-context

According to `WebAsyncManager` documentation,

> An async scenario starts with request processing as usual in a thread (T1). Concurrent request handling can be initiated by calling startCallableProcessing or startDeferredResultProcessing, both of which produce a result in a separate thread (T2). The result is saved and the request dispatched to the container, to resume processing with the saved result in a third thread (T3). Within the dispatched thread (T3), the saved result can be accessed via getConcurrentResult() or its presence detected via hasConcurrentResult().

The Spring `SecurityContext` is available in T1 and T2, but not in T3. I need the `SecurityContext` in T3, while serializing the response (it's a peculiar requirement). I can fix this by setting
`spring.security.filter.dispatcher-types=REQUEST,ERROR,ASYNC`, but this causes my entire `FilterChain` to run twice, which I'm trying to avoid.

Is there a way to get the `SecurityContext` in T3 without running the `FilterChain` again?

Comment: Could you include your current code, configuration, etc? without it will be quite complex provide you options

Comment: Did you read https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-async-security?